# Java: How can I set a boolean variable in a rental app to see if a payment has already been made?

Tags: java, boolean

Here is the code from my main file:

```
    if(passUser.checkIfAlreadyPaid()){
        System.out.println("You have already paid!");
    }
    else{
    System.out.println("Your bill of $" + passUser.getBill() + " has been paid. Thank you!");
    passUser.hasPaid();
    }
```

And here is the code from my class file:

```
public boolean hasPaid(){
    return true;
}

public boolean checkIfAlreadyPaid(){
    if(this.hasPaid()){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

When I run the main file, on the first run it is telling me that I have already paid. I feel like I am making something very simple too complicated. Can anyone help?

Comment: Because that's exactly what you wrote in your code.  If you don't want it to always return `true`, make it do something else.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You're asking why `return true;` always returns true?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349820/who-keeps-upvoting-these-terrible-questions

Comment: hasPaid is a method, and you should be storing it in a variable with a setter and getter- THEN check with if this.hasPaid-

Answer (score -1):

In your code snippet, the method hasPaid() is always true. Hence, you will always have the same output. My advise, covert hasPaid to a field and use a setter or getter to set and get the value.

```
private boolean hasPaid;

public void setHasPaid(boolean value) {
   this.hasPaid = value;
}

public boolean getHasPaid(){
   return this.hasPaid;
}
```

Comment: good start, but how would he structure his calls to these methods now?

Comment: @Jason, He needs a condition based on some values stored somewhere (a database or hardcoded) to set and then get the hasPaid variable later. In other words, hasPaid has to come from somewhere. yuin265 didn't share that detail.